# ORA-00937: not a single-group group function when using sub query

Tags: sql, oracle

The above error refers to fields in the sub query?? The sub query executes ok.But when the whole query runs I get the error and the fields in sub query are highlighted.

```
select sub.admyear,        
    count(sub.age),
    case when sub.age <=18 then '1-18'
        when sub.age <=25 then '19-25'
        when sub.age <=35 then '26-35'
        when sub.age <=45 then '36-45'
        when sub.age <=55 then '46-55'
        when sub.age <=65 then '56-65'
        when sub.age <=75 then '66-75'
        when sub.age <=85 then '76-85'
        when sub.age <=95 then '86-95'
        when sub.age <=105 then '96-105'
        else 'Over 105'
        end as agerange
from (select 
    extract(year from aip.adm_date)as admyear,
    trunc((aip.adm_date-cpi.birth_date)/365,0) as age,
    aip.pt_code
from k_archipreg aip, k_archptdxreg dx,k_cpireg cpi
where aip.adm_date between '01/01/2004' and '01/01/2014'
and dx.pt_code = aip.pt_code
and cpi.pt_code = aip.pt_code
and DX.EVENT_NO = AIP.EVENT_NO
and dx.nmds_dx_code like 'J%'
)sub
group by  admyear,
     case when age >0 and age <=18 then '1-18'
        when age <=25 then '19-25'
        when age <=35 then '26-35'
        when age <=45 then '36-45'
        when age <=55 then '46-55'
        when age <=65 then '56-65'
        when age <=75 then '66-75'
        when age <=85 then '76-85'
        when age <=95 then '86-95'
        when age <=105 then '96-105'
        else 'Over 105'
        end
```

Comment: You should fix the second `age <=95` in the `case` statement.  Although there are things I personally don't like about your query, I don't see this error in it.  Are you sure this is the query that was submitted?

Comment: Yes it is the same query.  Thanks for the spot about 'age <=95' When the error happens The aip on this line 
trunc((**aip**.adm_date-cpi.birth_date)/365,0) as age
is highlighted all other aip in the sub query are also highlighted but not to the same extent.
Query editor is Toad v11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried including `count(sub.age)` in the `group by` statement?

Comment: thanks Emanuel, that was the answer. Obvious when you see it, thanks again.

Comment: Please explain.  Aggregation functions usually generate an error in a `group by` statement.

Comment: Hi Gordon, in the select the fields where aliased sub. but not in the group by. removing the alias allowed the query to execute without an error but didn't return what I thought it would, the grouping isn't right but that will have to be another question.

Comment: I don't think that should make a difference because you have only one table alias in the `from` clause.  There is no danger of an ambiguous reference.